# C Sharp - Interfaces which Require Object References

Tags: c#, object, interface, reference

For some reason when I call a namespace within this class, I get an error which states that 
it requires an object reference. I thought that using a reference variable of the IMethodResponses type would allow me to access a method within its own creation, but 
I can't accomplish this, and nor can I simply just implement the interface without a reference and use its methods...

Can someone help me out with this? I'll post the Interface itself too in case their's something wrong. I should probably note that I haven't been doing this very long.

//Class Implementing Interface:

```
internal sealed class Name : INameCreation, IMethodResponses
{
    public ScratchCreate create = ScratchCreate.create;
    ListCreate select = new ListCreate();
    public IMethodResponses _responses = IMethodResponses; //<--Error

    public static void ChooseName()
    {
        int response;

        Console.WriteLine("Press \'1\' to select from a list of names, or \'2\' to create your own.");
        Console.WriteLine("If you wish to quit, you may do so by pressing \'0\'");
        response = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you didn't enter any of the correct responses...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press \'1\' to select from a list of names, or \'2\' to create your own.");
            Console.WriteLine("If you wish to quit, you may do so by pressing \'0\'");
            response = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        while (response != 0 || response != 1 || response != 2);

        _responses.IntegerResponse(response);

    }

    public void IntegerResponse(int response)
    {
        switch (response)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
                break;
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:

                break;

        }
    }
```

//Interface:

```
namespace PlayerCreation
 {
     public interface INameCreation
     { 

     }
     public interface IMethodResponses 
     {
        void IntegerResponse(int response);
        void StringResponse(string response);
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Are you forgetting to implement StringResponse?

Comment: I realize this isn't about your question but you probably want to use int.TryParse instead of parse. If a user enters 'a' instead of a number your program will blow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your IntegerResponse method static you can call it with:

```
Name.IntegerResponse(...);
```

For:

```
public IMethodResponses _responses = IMethodResponses;
```

From a static method you can acess only static members.
Setting an type into a variable of the same type won't work.
What is expected to fit into _responses is an **instance** of any class of its type or any class that implements its interface (**IMethodResponses**). Since you cannot create an instance of an interface than it is the latter.

```
public static IMethodResponses _responses = new Name();
```

This will work but is not needed, since IntegerResponse can safely be made static as is by using the static keyword before the method definition.

What is a bit awkward is the use of `public static void ChooseName()`. This method is static and returns nothing. It just uses Console.Writeline. You will find out that as soon as you start developing a real application this will need to be redone.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. This helped me see things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a reference variable of type IMethodResponses with a type, and not an instance of a type.

In order to fix this, you can simply do the following:

```
public Name()
{
    _responses = (IMethodResponses)this;
}
```

Edit: Also I just noticed, there are two other problems with your code:
1. _responses is non-static and you are accessing this variable in a static class, which will not work.
2. StringResponses has not been implemented.

If you want to maintain ChooseName as static and have access to the same instance, then you'll have to implement a singleton.

Comment: In order to do this (i.e. follow the code sample in my comment), the method (ChooseName) has to be non-static. If the method is static, the class has to be a singleton. If the class is static, then you can't implement the interfaces.